# While running the Karate test for UI actions, on Jenkins using docker image , I am not able to run the same

Tags: docker, karate

While trying to running the Karate test for UI actions, using docker image i.e "https://hub.docker.com/r/ptrthomas/karate-chrome" , I am not able to run the same.

I have used below commands as per the document "[https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker"][1]

```
docker run --name karate --rm -p 5901:5900 --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v "$PWD":/src ptrthomas/karate-chrome
```

and once it is running I run the below Command

```
docker exec -it -w /src karate mvn clean test -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=docker'
```

Feature file as below

```
Feature: Verify that in case of valid credentials, user is able to login in  Window as well as session token is generated successfully.

  Background: 
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome'}

  Scenario: Verify that in case of valid credentials, user is able to login in Fusion Auth Window as well as session token is generated successfully.
    Given driver 'http://globaldeveloperexperience.ilb.dev.pdx13.clover.network/globaldeveloperexperience/login'
    And waitFor('input[id=loginId]')
    And input('input[id=loginId]', 'developer-platform-clover-connect@clover.com')
    And input('input[id=password]', 'Test0101@')
    When click('.blue')
    Then waitFor('pre')
    And json response = text('pre')
    And match response.sessionToken == '#notnull'
```

Runner class as below:

```
package com.gde.automation.gdeTestRunners;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate.Test;

public class gdeTestCaseRunner {

    @Test
    public Karate runTestUsingClassPath() {
        return Karate.run("classpath:com/gde/automation/gdeTestCases/LoginFlow/validateSessionToken.feature");
    }
}
```

Karate-config.js file as below

```
function fn() {
  var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'staging';
  }
  var config = {
    env: env,
    myVarName: 'someValue'
  }
  if (env == 'dev') {
    // customize
    // e.g. config.foo = 'bar';
  } else if (env == 'e2e') {
    // customize
  }
  return config;
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
 Still I am getting the below error:
T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.gde.automation.ParallelBuilderWithCucumberReport
09:19:45.299 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - using system property 'karate.env': staging
09:19:46.281 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
09:19:49.693 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: staging 
09:19:49.986 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - found / verified free local port: 37353
09:19:49.987 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - preferred port 9222 not available, will use: 37353
09:19:49.992 [chrome_1650532789980] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - command: [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=37353, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/src/target/chrome_1650532789980, --disable-popup-blocking], working dir: target/chrome_1650532789980
09:19:49.994 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #0 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:50.032 [chrome_1650532789980-out] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - [898:898:0421/091950.031354:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
09:19:50.036 [chrome_1650532789980] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=37353, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/src/target/chrome_1650532789980, --disable-popup-blocking] working dir: target/chrome_1650532789980
09:19:50.255 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #1 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:50.508 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #2 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:50.760 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #3 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:51.015 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #4 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:51.267 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #5 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:51.519 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #6 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:51.773 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #7 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:52.025 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #8 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:52.278 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #9 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:52.530 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #10 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:52.782 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #11 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:53.035 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #12 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:53.287 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #13 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:53.540 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #14 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:53.792 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #15 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:54.044 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #16 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:54.296 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #17 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:54.549 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #18 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:54.802 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #19 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:55.054 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.chrome_1650532789980 - poll attempt #20 for port to be ready - localhost:37353
09:19:55.826 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > GET http://localhost:37353/json
1 > Host: localhost:37353
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_322)
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate


09:19:55.883 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:37353 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 528 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:37353/json
09:19:57.885 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - attempt #1 waiting for http to be ready at: http://localhost:37353/json
09:19:57.889 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
2 > GET http://localhost:37353/json
2 > Host: localhost:37353
2 > Connection: Keep-Alive
2 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_322)
2 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Comment: sorry I can't help here. hopefully some jenkins expert can weigh in

Comment: @PeterThomas I rephrase the question with more clarity. I humbly request to have a second look on the same. May be you can help now

Comment: my advice is please go through these docs and try to compare: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker

Comment: @PeterThomas as per your suggestion I changed the docker commands, but unfortunately getting the error. I rephrase the errors again and mention the new errors. It seems my connection is getting refused.  "karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:"

Comment: I honestly have no more ideas. karate is an open source project, it does depend on the community to help also. I will just say that the info in the link I provided above works fine for me and many others

Comment: I saw your answer (which will definitely be removed as per stack overflow guidelines). I **cannot** help you on "local" the reason the docker image exists is to avoid all these issues on local depending on os, machine, version, permissions, etc. please figure out how to use the docker container or get some expert to look at your local machine setup, no one else can help you

Comment: for those who land here in future, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2358